# Mudar dinamicamente URL de vídeo dentro de janela Lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, minha questao é sobre mudança dinamica de url de vídeo. Ao clicar numa função (abrirlightbox) abre uma janela lightbox, e dentro dessa janaela preciso abrir video dinamicamente, hoje abre um estático.

Tenho dois segmentos (carro e moto), dentro de cada um segmento tenho dois box que ao ser clicado aparece um thumb/imagem onde ao ser clicada carrega o vídeo correspondente.

Quando clico num box abre embaixo a thumb e quando clico no outro box abre a mesma thumb. Ao clicar nessa thumb aciona a função que monta o lightbox com o vídeo. O o objetivo é abri esses vídeos dinamicamente.

'data-veiculo' é um 'attr' que identifica o box selecionado.

```
function selecionaUrl(veiculos) {
    var boxA = $(".box-veiculo[data-veiculo=A]");
    var boxB = $(".box-veiculo[data-veiculo=B]");
    if (veiculoSegmento == 'carros'){
        if (boxA == $(".box-veiculo-selected")){
            $('#video').attr("href", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxx");
            return true;    
        }
        else if (boxB == $(".box-veiculo-selected")){
            $('#video').attr("href", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/yyyyy");
            return true;    
        }

    }else if (veiculoSegmento == 'motos'){
        if (boxA == $(".box-veiculo-selected")){
            $('#video').attr("href", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/wwwww");
            return true;    
        }
        else if (boxB == $(".box-veiculo-selected")){
            $('#video').attr("href", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/zzzzz");
            return true;    
        }
    }
}
```

Dentro do arquivo `js`, a variável que monta o lightbox e sendo concatenado por (veiculos):

```
var htmllgtbox = '<div id="" </div> ' + '<iframe ' + veiculos + '</iframe>'
```

Comment: Vc quer que essas URLs, por exemplo, `https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxx`sejam dinâmicas nessa função acima, vindo de acordo com o thumb clicado?

Comment: DvD, sim, ao clicar no thumb chamo a função via href="javascript:abrirlightbox();"
essa função chama uma outra função com uma variável que monta a lightbox, nessa var  concateno o vídeo

Comment: Tem uns problemas no seu código, e um já até corrigi: tinha um `}` sobrando no final. E em alguns `if` você colocou apenas um `=`, quando o correto seriam dois `==`.

Comment: Pra início, já pode ir pensando em enviar para a função que abre os vídeos o código do YT do vídeo, algo do tipo: `javascript:abrirlightbox('codigo_video')`... e enviar isso para a função `selecionaUrlVeiculo()`

Comment: sim, tive que fazer o código novamente, pois no ambiente que estou não posso copiar o código, tive que refazer fora

Comment: DVD, tenho 4 videos diferentes, preciso chama-los de forma dinâmica, não chamando junto com a função abrirlightbox.

Comment: tenho apenas uma thumb que chama a função abrirlightbox
quando clico num box abre embaixo a thumb quando clico no outro box abre a mesma thumb

Comment: Seria interessante reformular a pergunta, colocar os códigos envolvidos nisso tudo. Pra mim ainda ficou confuso.

Comment: DvD, o código que fiz é esse mesmo, mas que pode ser feito de outra maneira para carregar dinâmica, pois possivelmente pode ter muito mais vídeos para carregar.

Comment: Não seria enviar um parâmetro com o código do vídeo pra função `selecionaUrlVeiculo()`?

Comment: Não entendi a variável `selecionaUrlVeiculo` se ela é uma função.

Comment: não, a variavel é **htmllgtbox**

Comment: `'<iframe ' + selecionaUrlVeiculo + '</iframe>'`.  O `selecionaUrlVeiculo` é uma variável.

Comment: Pelo código na pergunta, isso está sendo uma variável e uma função ao mesmo tempo. Muito confuso.

Comment: tem a variavel, e como enviar um parâmetro com o código do vídeo pra função selecionaUrlVeiculo()?